# How to filter firebase data and insert into table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to filter my data according to my session column but after searching everywhere I could not find a solution.It would really be helpful if you could send me a sample code that filters and then appends to my table.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Orders");

rootRef.on("child_added",snap => {

var user_id=snap.child("User id").val();

var name=snap.child("Username").val().toUpperCase();

var email=snap.child("Email").val();

var dabba_type=snap.child("Dabba Type").val().toUpperCase();

var address=snap.child("Address").val().toLowerCase();

var start=snap.child("Start date").val();

var end=snap.child("End date").val();

var session=snap.child("Session").val().toUpperCase();

var feedback=snap.child("Feedback").val();

var phone=snap.child("Phone number").val();

$("#table_body").append("<tr> <td>"+ user_id +

"</td> <td>" + name + 

"</td> <td>" + email +

"</td><td>" + address +

"</td><td>" + dabba_type + 

"</td><td>" + session + 

"</td><td>" + start +

"</td><td>" + end + 

"</td><td>" + phone +

"</td><td>" + feedback 

+ "</td></tr>" );
});

});
```

Comment: Consider using jQuery libs to do this. There are many great libraries depending on the level of complexity/functionality you require. My personal recommendation: [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/). Otherwise this [google search](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=javascript+table+filter+library) is pretty informative.

Comment: The documentation on filtering data in a Firebase Database query is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it using `v-data` table:

```
<div ref="content" id="tabela">
    <v-container>
      {{ this.filter_data.Naslov }}
      <v-data-table
        v-model="selected"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="filter_data[0]"
        item-key="ID_Naloge"
        show-select
        :items-per-page="10"
        class="elevation-1"
        :search="model"
      >    
      </v-data-table>
    </v-container>
```

and this is function "tabela()":

```
 tabela(){
      db.collection("Kontrolne naloge")
      .where("Naslov", "==", this.selected2)
      .get().then( (snapshot) => {
        const documents = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        this.filter_data.splice(this.event);
        this.filter_data.push(documents);
      });
      return console.log(this.filter_data);
 },
```